# Statistical testing: Is the sample representative of the population (discrete data)

Tags: statistics

Anyone with an interest in Statistics,

It might seem a slightly ill-formed question, in the sense that 'representative' is not well defined but I will try. 
For two of my students completing an IB investigation (Grade 11/12) I have Student A has collected data on the number of occurrences of event A, and Event B and is performing a chi-squared test of independence.

Student B has independently reached a very similar idea of collection of data on the occurrences of Event A, and Event C and proposes also performing a chi-squared test of independence.

The level of similarity is uncomfortable to me so I wondered how it would be possible for student B to salvage her data, and not need to start back at the data collection.

The discrete nature of the data is confusing me as it is necessary for all students to be sufficiently unique.  As an alternative, is there a good test, for example, for her test percentages of data falling into different labels for her sample, with the percentage of different data falling into the same labels for the population to make inferences about whether the sample is representative of the population, or whether the differences are statistically significant (ie.  the sample does not fit the general trend of the population).

It's discrete data, so I'm really unsure as these are all people counts.

Kind regards,
Cliff

Comment: It is not very clear (to me at least !) what you are asking. The problem seems to be that both students have collected similar data (both about Event A), but afterwards I don't really understand what you are looking for, or testing...

Comment: Hi,  thanks response Evergalo.                                                               
Event A sample:  Category A - 5%, Category B - 25%, Category C - 25% etc.    Event A population - Category A - 10%, Category B- 20% ......,  Is it possible to do anything with this data as an alternative?

Comment: Yes, you can use a Chi-squared-test to see if the sample is representative of the population with regards to the Event A...

Comment: It sounds good but I just want to clarify.  This would be a chi-squared test of fit rather test of independence?